# How can I enable Gradle Build Cache when running Gradle build with Coverity?

Tags: gradle, coverity

I have a simple Gradle project that has `org.gradle.caching=true` set in `gradle.properties` in order to enable the local build cache.

When I run the build directly (`./gradlew clean build`) I can see that the local build cache is being used: https://scans.gradle.com/s/ykywrv3lzik3s/performance/build-cache

However, when I run the build with Coverity (`bin/cov-build --dir cov-int ./gradlew clean build`) I see the build cache is disabled for the same build: https://scans.gradle.com/s/j2pvoyhgzvvxk/performance/build-cache

How is Coverity causing the build cache to be disabled, and is there a way to run a build with Coverity *and* the Gradle Build Cache?

Answer (score 0):

You can't use the build cache with Coverity, or at least you don't want to.

The Gradle [Build Cache](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/build_cache.html) causes compilation to be skipped:

> The Gradle build cache is a cache mechanism that aims to save time by reusing outputs produced by other builds. The build cache works by storing (locally or remotely) build outputs and allowing builds to fetch these outputs from the cache when it is determined that inputs have not changed, avoiding the expensive work of regenerating them.

Were that mechanism to be used with Coverity, it would prevent `cov-build` from seeing the compilation steps, and hence it would be unable to perform its own compilation of the source code, which is a necessary prerequisite to performing its static analysis.

I don't know precisely how Coverity is disabling the cache (or if that is even intentional on Coverity's part), but if it didn't do so, then you would have to yourself, as described in the Synopsys article [Cov-build using gradle shows "No files were emitted" error message](https://community.synopsys.com/s/article/Cov-build-using-gradle-shows-No-files-were-emitted-error-message), the key step of which is:

> Use "clean" and  "cleanBuildCache" task to remove all saved cache data which prevent full compilation.

before running `cov-build`.